# I keep getting errors in my Gulp SASS setup due to the import stylesheet

Tags: sass, gulp

Hi everybody I'm new to learning Gulp and I can't seem to get over this hurdle. I am trying to compile my sass and I will set it to gulp-watch. It will work fine for a little while, but then it will show an error- the file is not found or unreadable.It looks something like:

events.js:154
    throw er;// Unhandled 'error' event

Error: app/scss/main.sass
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: layout1
Parent style sheet: stdin on line 2 of stdin

I have tried to look on this site for the solution to my problem and I thought putting the includePaths would work (maybe I'm doing it wrong) but I'm still getting errors. Could someone please help me out?Here are some images of my project. Here is a link to some pictures:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zMKg.jpg

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code or errors, that makes it impossible for people who would be willing to help you copy/paste into their own editors.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like there are a few issues:

1) You should probably use the `scss` extension with all your files and update the sass task in your gulp file to watch for changes like so: `gulp.src('app/scss/*.scss')` or since, in theory, all files contained in that folder should be sass, you could do this instead: `gulp.src('app/scss/*')` which will watch all the files in the directory.

2) There's also an issue with the names of your sass files. You need to prepend the files you wish to import with an underscore so the compiler knows these files are partials.

So your sass files should look like:

```
_layout1.scss
main.scss
_normalize.scss
_styles.scss
```

And import the partials in `main.scss`:

```
@import 'normalize';
@import 'layout1';
@import 'styles';
```

More info http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-4

Comment: Thanks for answering this, I'll try to see if this works!

Comment: I've got a question, does this mean I can't use regular sass or do I have to switch over to scss?

Comment: I suppose the compiler will read both file types. Have you tried keeping the file extensions as they are, prepending with an underscore and changing the source of the sass gulp task to `gulp.src('app/scss/*')`?

Comment: It kinda works, i need to hit ctrl + s repeatedly until it runs though. Not sure if that's the way it's supposed to be.

Comment: How is any of this going to solve a "file not found" error?  If the OP was using the wrong extension for the syntax they are using, it would give an entirely different error.

Comment: The file wasn't found because the import in main.scss was looking for partial files prepended with an underscore. The suggested changes to the gulp file were mostly tangential. I suppose this should have been #2.

Comment: @damien9999 Are you making changes in between saves? Are you still experiencing the delayed results?